# Help with advanced syntax rules

Tags: syntax-highlighting, syntax-table

How can I express syntax rules like "`[0-9/.:*+!_'?-]` are valid symbol constituent, but not as the first char"?

Or "`/` is a valid symbol constituent, but can only appear once and in the middle of a symbol".

Comment: I'm afraid that that's not possible with syntax tables, they are just simple classifiers. You'd probably want to take a look at [Semantic](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Semantic.html)

Comment: I am no expert, however syntax-propertize-function can express these more complicated rules like you describe. You can provide regular expressions (which should be able to describe such conditional behavior) via syntax-propertize-rules clauses.